# Operators on $\operatorname{Im}(M^{1/2})$ and equality between two supremums.

Tags: operator-theory

Let $\mathcal{B}(F)$ the algebra of all bounded linear operators on a complex Hilbert space $(F,\|\cdot\|)$. Let $M\in \mathcal{B}(F)$ be a positive semidefinite operator.

The normed space $(\operatorname{Im}(M^{1/2}),\|\cdot\|_{\operatorname{Im}(M^{1/2})})$ is Hilbert, where
$$\|M^{1/2}x\|_{\operatorname{Im}(M^{1/2})}=\|P_{\overline{\operatorname{Im}(M)}}x\|,\;\forall\, x\in F$$

If $S$ is a bounded operator on $\operatorname{Im}(M^{1/2})$, then we can prove that
$$\|S\|=\sup_{\substack{x\in \overline{\operatorname{Im}(M^{1/2})},\\ x\not=0}} \frac{\|SM^{1/2}x\|_{\operatorname{Im}(M^{1/2})}}{\|M^{1/2}x\|_{\operatorname{Im}(M^{1/2})}}.$$

> I want to prove that 
>   $$\sup_{\substack{x\in \overline{\operatorname{Im}(M^{1/2})},\\ x\not=0}} \frac{\|SM^{1/2}x\|_{\operatorname{Im}(M^{1/2})}}{\|M^{1/2}x\|_{\operatorname{Im}(M^{1/2})}}=\sup_{\substack{x\in \overline{\operatorname{Im}(M)},\\ x\not=0}} \frac{\|SMx\|_{\operatorname{Im}(M^{1/2})}}{\|Mx\|_{\operatorname{Im}(M^{1/2})}}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's  prove $\overline{\operatorname{Im} M} = \overline{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}$.

For $y = Mx \in \operatorname{Im}M$ we have $y = Mx = M^{1/2}(M^{1/2}x) \in \operatorname{Im}M^{1/2}$.

Hence $\operatorname{Im}M \subseteq \operatorname{Im}M^{1/2}$. By taking the closures it follows $\overline{\operatorname{Im}M} \subseteq \overline{\operatorname{Im}M^{1/2}}$.

For the converse inclusion, [you can see](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2802363/144766) that every $y = M^{1/2}x \in \operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}$ can be expressed as a limit

$$y = Mx = \lim_{n\to\infty} Mx_n$$

of a sequence $(Mx_n)_n$ in $\operatorname{Im} M$ so we conclude $\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2} \subseteq \overline{\operatorname{Im} M}$. By taking the closures we conclude $\overline{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}} \subseteq \overline{\operatorname{Im} M}$.

---

Let $x \in \overline{\operatorname{Im} M}$, $x \ne 0$ be arbitrary. Define $y = M^{1/2}x \in \operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}$. Since $x \in \overline{\operatorname{Im} M} = \overline{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}$ certainly $x \perp \ker M^{1/2}$ and $x \ne 0$ so $y = M^{1/2}x \ne 0$. We have

$$\frac{\|SMx\|_{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}}{\|Mx\|_{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}} = \frac{\|SM^{1/2}y\|_{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}}{\|M^{1/2}y\|_{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}}$$

Therefore

$$\left\{\frac{\|SMx\|_{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}}{\|Mx\|_{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}} : x \in  \overline{\operatorname{Im} M}, x \ne 0\right\}\subseteq\left\{\frac{\|SM^{1/2}x\|_{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}}{\|M^{1/2}x\|_{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}} : x \in  \overline{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}, x \ne 0\right\}$$

For the converse inclusion, let $y \in \overline{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}$, $y \ne 0$. There exists a sequence $(y_n)_n$ in $\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}$ such that $y_n \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} y$. We can assume that $y_n \ne 0, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. There exists a sequence $(x_n)_n$ in $F$ such that $y_n = M^{1/2}x, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. We can choose $x_n$ to be in $\overline{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}$ because of the decomposition $F = \overline{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}} \oplus \ker M^{1/2}$. We then also have $x_n \in \overline{\operatorname{Im} M}$ and $x_n \ne 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Now we have

\begin{align}
\frac{\|SM^{1/2}y\|_{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}}{\|M^{1/2}y\|_{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}} &= \frac{\|SM^{1/2}(\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n)\|_{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}}{\|M^{1/2}(\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n)\|_{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}}\\
&= \frac{\lim_{n\to\infty}\|SM^{1/2}y_n\|_{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}}{\lim_{n\to\infty}\|M^{1/2}y_n\|_{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}}\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\|SM^{1/2}y_n\|_{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}}{\|M^{1/2}y_n\|_{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}}\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\|SM^{1/2}M^{1/2}x_n\|_{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}}{\|M^{1/2}M^{1/2}x_n\|_{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}}\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\|SMx_n\|_{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}}{\|Mx_n\|_{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}} \in \overline{\left\{\frac{\|SMx\|_{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}}{\|Mx\|_{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}} : x \in  \overline{\operatorname{Im} M}, x \ne 0\right\}}
\end{align}

because each of $\frac{\|SMx_n\|_{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}}{\|Mx_n\|_{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}}$ is an element of $\left\{\frac{\|SMx\|_{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}}{\|Mx\|_{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}} : x \in  \overline{\operatorname{Im} M}, x \ne 0\right\}$.

We conclude

$$\left\{\frac{\|SM^{1/2}x\|_{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}}{\|M^{1/2}x\|_{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}} : x \in  \overline{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}, x \ne 0\right\} \subseteq \overline{\left\{\frac{\|SMx\|_{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}}{\|Mx\|_{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}} : x \in  \overline{\operatorname{Im} M}, x \ne 0\right\}}$$

So we have the equality of closures

$$\overline{\left\{\frac{\|SM^{1/2}x\|_{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}}{\|M^{1/2}x\|_{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}} : x \in  \overline{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}, x \ne 0\right\}} = \overline{\left\{\frac{\|SMx\|_{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}}{\|Mx\|_{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}} : x \in  \overline{\operatorname{Im} M}, x \ne 0\right\}}$$

Finally

\begin{align}
\|S\|_{\mathcal{B}(\operatorname{Im}M^{1/2})} &= \sup \left\{\frac{\|SM^{1/2}x\|_{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}}{\|M^{1/2}x\|_{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}} : x \in  \overline{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}, x \ne 0\right\} \\
&= \sup\overline{\left\{\frac{\|SM^{1/2}x\|_{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}}{\|M^{1/2}x\|_{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}} : x \in  \overline{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}, x \ne 0\right\}}\\
&= \sup \overline{\left\{\frac{\|SMx\|_{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}}{\|Mx\|_{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}} : x \in  \overline{\operatorname{Im} M}, x \ne 0\right\}}\\
&= \sup \left\{\frac{\|SMx\|_{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}}{\|Mx\|_{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}} : x \in  \overline{\operatorname{Im} M}, x \ne 0\right\}
\end{align}

because for any nonempty $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ we have $\sup A= \sup \overline{A}$.

Comment: @Schüler Ah, yes, you are right. Then the two definitions are in fact equivalent.  You can do the same trick to show $$\sup \left\{\frac{\|Sx\|_{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}}{\|x\|_{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}} : x \in \overline{\operatorname{Im} M} , x \ne 0\right\}=\sup\left\{ \frac{\|SMx\|_{\operatorname{Im}M^{1/2}}}{\|Mx\|_{\operatorname{Im}M^{1/2}}};\;x\in \overline{\operatorname{Im}M},\,x\neq 0\right\}$$ and the apply my answer.

Comment: @Schüler You were right, it was not obvious. I have changed my answer to a detailed direct proof. Let me know if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 2):

If you had $M^{1/2}$ instead of $M$, it's just the definition of norm.

What happens is just that $$\overline{\text{Im}\,M^{1/2}}=\overline{\text{Im}\,M}$$ Then inclusion $\supset$ is simply $M=M^{1/2}M^{1/2}$, while the inclusion $\subset$ follows from instance from the fact that $M^{1/2}$ is a limit of polynomials (without independent coefficient) in $M$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't understand how to show the inclusion $\subset$? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'll explain, but for that answer me this question: what is $M^{1/2}$?

Comment: Thank you very much. It's the square root of the positive operator $M$. It satisfy $M=M^{1/2}M^{1/2}$

Comment: Yes. And how do you know such an operator exists?

Comment: Since M is positive. I think that every positive operator has a square root.

Comment: Indeed. But if you understand **why** such operator exists, you'll understand why for any $x$ there is a sequence ${x_n}\}$ with $M^{1/2}x=\lim_n Mx_n$.

Comment: I don't understand how in the one hand $\overline{\text{Im}\,M^{1/2}}=\overline{\text{Im}\,M}$ and in the other hand $\text{Im}(M)$ is dense in $\text{Im}(M^{1/2})$. Please see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2865183/under-which-topology-we-have-the-density-of-textimm-in-textimm1-2

Comment: Not sure what the question is. If $B\subset A$ and $B$ is dense in $A$, then by definition $\overline B=\overline A$.