# Density of the range of a positive operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $\mathcal{B}(F)$ the algebra of all bounded linear operators on a complex Hilbert space $(F,\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$. Let $M\in \mathcal{B}(F)^+$ (i.e. $\langle Mx\;, \;x\rangle\geq 0$ for all $x\in F$).

> Why  for any $x\in F$ there exists a sequence $(x_n)_n$ with 
>   $$M^{1/2}x=\lim_{n\to \infty} Mx_n\;?$$

Comment: Do you know the spectral theorem?

Comment: Yes i Know it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a sequence of polynomials
$$p_0(t) = 0$$
$$p_{n+1}(t) = p_n(t) + \frac12\left(t - p_n(t)^2\right), \quad\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$$

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/815156/144766) shows that $p_n(M) \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} M^{1/2}$ in the strong operator topology.

Notice that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $p_n(0) = 0$ so we can write $p_n(t) = tq_n(t)$. Now for any vector $x$ we have

$$M^{1/2}x = \lim_{n\to\infty} p_n(M)x = \lim_{n\to\infty} M(q_n(M)x)$$

which is the desired claim.

Comment: @Schüler I have added an answer. I believe you are working with the wrong definition of the operator norm on $\mathcal{B}(\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2})$ induced by $\|\cdot\|_{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}$.

Comment: @Schüler It proves that $\operatorname{Im} M$ is dense in $\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}$ with respect to the norm $\|\cdot\|$.

Comment: But $\overline{\operatorname{Im} M} = \overline{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}$. I understand thta $\operatorname{Im} M$ and $\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}$ have the same closure with respect to $\|\cdot\|$. Please correct me if i made a wrong.

Comment: Do you agree with me? Thanks a lot

Comment: @Schüler Yes, since $\operatorname{Im} M \subseteq \operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}$ that implies that $\operatorname{Im} M$ is dense in $\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}$. Indeed, every $x \in \operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}$ is in $\overline{\operatorname{Im} M}$ so there exists a sequence $(x_n)_n$ in $\operatorname{Im} M$ which converges to $x$.

Comment: Under which norm you made the  closure of Im(M)? Thank you

Comment: @Schüler The norm of the Hilbert space in question, induced by $\langle\cdot, \cdot\rangle$.

Comment: When you say that $\operatorname{Im} M$ is dense in $\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}$ with respect to the norm induced by $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$, this means that $\overline{\operatorname{Im} M}^{\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle}=\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}$. However, we have $\overline{\operatorname{Im}M}^{\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle}= \overline{\operatorname{Im}M^{1/2}}^{\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle}$. Please where is my wrong? Thank you.

Comment: @Schüler The closure in the equality $\overline{\operatorname{Im} M}^{\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle}=\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}$ is taken in the subspace topology of $\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}$ and the closures in the equality $\overline{\operatorname{Im}M}^{\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle}= \overline{\operatorname{Im}M^{1/2}}^{\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle}$ are both with respect to the topology of the space $H$.

Comment: @Schüler Therefore:
$$\overline{\operatorname{Im} M}^{\operatorname{Im}M^{1/2}} = \overline{\operatorname{Im} M}^{H} \cap \operatorname{Im}M^{1/2} = \overline{\operatorname{Im} M^{1/2}}^H \cap \operatorname{Im}M^{1/2} =  \operatorname{Im}M^{1/2}$$

Comment: Please what is the expression of $p_n(t)$? I ask you because I don't see why $p_n(0)=0$? Thanks

Comment: Dear mechanodroid, I would like to focus your attention that in [this answer]: [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/814720/square-root-of-a-hermitian-operator-exists/815156#815156] the operator $M$ is assumed to be less than $I$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $M=\int \lambda \,\mathrm{d}E_\lambda$ be the spectral decomposition. Let $x_n=\int_{\lambda>1/n}\lambda^{-1/2}E_{\lambda}(x)\,\mathrm{d}E_\lambda$. Then for any $y$ you have $$\langle Mx_n\mid y \rangle=\int_{\lambda>1/n}\langle \lambda^{1/2}E_{\lambda}(x)\mid y \rangle\,\mathrm{d}E_\lambda=\langle M^{1/2} x\mid y\rangle-\int_{\lambda\leq 1/n}\langle \lambda^{1/2}E_{\lambda}(x)\mid y\rangle \,\mathrm{d}E_\lambda.$$

But $\lvert\langle \lambda^{1/2}E_\lambda(x)\mid y\rangle\rvert\leq\lambda^{1/2}\lVert x\rVert\lVert y\rVert$, so for fixed $x$ and $\lVert y\rVert\leq 1$ it tends to zero uniformly (in $y$) as $\lambda\to 0$. The conclusion follows.

More directly, $Mx_n-M^{1/2}x=\int_{\lambda\leq 1/n}\lambda^{1/2}E_\lambda(x) \,\mathrm{d}E_\lambda$, and likewise $\lVert \lambda^{1/2}E_\lambda(x)\rVert\leq \lambda^{1/2}\lVert x\rVert$.

Comment: @Schüler: What's wrong with Martin Agerami's answer there? The inclusion $\subseteq$ is exactly this question!

Comment: @Schüler: The second inclusion is trivial even without the closure: $M^{1/2}(M^{1/2}x)=M(x)$.

Comment: @Schüler: I would argue it's overly detailed, but okay. I don't see what you expect from me.

Comment: In your direct method, I don't understand how you get $$Mx_n-M^{1/2}x=\int_{\lambda\leq 1/n}\lambda^{1/2}E_\lambda(x) \,\mathrm{d}E_\lambda .$$ Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Schüler: $Mx_n=\int_{\lambda>1/n}\lambda\cdot\lambda^{-1/2}E_\lambda(x)\,\mathrm{d}E_\lambda$.

Comment: @Schüler: The RHS of the inequality doesn't make sense, you can't take $\lambda^{1/2}$ out. There is no reason for that last integral to converge to $0$ (for example, if $M=0$, then it is the identity function).

Comment: @Schüler: This need not be true, as I have said. You don't need the integral to tend to zero, only to be uniformly bounded.

Comment: @Schüler: Not quite. $\mathrm{d}E_\lambda$ is an operator-valued measure, so it doesn't make sense. You need to add $\lVert\cdot\rVert$. Otherwise, yes, I agree.