# Spectral decomposition of a positive operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $M:=\displaystyle\int_0^{+\infty} \lambda \,\mathrm{d}E_\lambda$ be the spectral decomposition of a positive operator $M$ on a complex Hilbert space $F$.

For $x\in F$, we set
 $$x_n=\displaystyle\int_{\{\lambda>1/n\}}\lambda^{-1/2}E_{\lambda}(x)\,\mathrm{d}E_\lambda.$$

> Why 
>    $$Mx_n=\int_{\{\lambda> 1/n\}}\lambda\lambda^{-1/2}E_\lambda(x) \,\mathrm{d}E_\lambda?$$

Comment: I don't understand how to interchange between the two integrals

Comment: In general you have $\int f(\lambda) dE_{\lambda}\int g(\lambda)dE_{\lambda}=\int f(\lambda)g(\lambda) dE_{\lambda}$

Comment: @LorenzoQuarisa It is correct to write $E_{\lambda}(x)$? Is $E_{\lambda}$ an operator which actes on $F$? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, $E_{\lambda}:F\to F$ is an orthogonal projection on $F$.

Comment: @LorenzoQuarisa $\mathrm{d}E_\lambda$ is a measure or just a notation?

Comment: It can be seen as a $\sigma$-additive map $E:\Omega \mapsto E(\Omega)$ which maps  each measurable set $\Omega$ onto an orthogonal projection $E(\Omega)$. This is called a projection valued measure. But it is not a "true" measure so integration needs to be redefined accordingly.

Comment: $E_{\lambda}dE_{\lambda}x$ can make sense. However, $E_{\lambda}x dE_{\lambda}$ does not make sense because you have a vector on the left an operator $dE_{\lambda}$.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Why $\mathrm{d}E_\lambda(x)$ make sense? Could you please provide me the correct answer? Thank you.

Comment: This link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection-valued_measure may be useful to you.

Comment: Think of this is a Riemann-Stieltjes integral, which it can be. What does $E_{\lambda}x \Delta E_{\lambda}$ mean? How are you going to interpret so that it does make sense?

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts What do you mean by the symbol $\Delta$? Thank you.

Comment: How are you making sense of this integral? That seems to be at the heart of the problem.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts For $u\in F$ the map
\begin{eqnarray*}
\rho_u: \mathbb{R}&\longrightarrow& \mathbb{R}_+\\
\lambda&\longmapsto& \|E_\lambda u\|_{F}^2=\langle E_\lambda u ,u \rangle,
\end{eqnarray*}
is a right continuous, nonnegative, nondecreasing function and tends to zero for $\lambda\longrightarrow -\infty$ and to $\|u\|^2$ for $\lambda\longrightarrow \infty$. We conclude that $\rho_u$ is a distribution function then there exist a finite Borel measure $\mu_u$ satisfying
$$\mu_u ([a,b[)=\rho_u(b^-)-\rho_u(a) \ ; \ \mu_u (\{\lambda\})=\rho_u(\lambda^-)-\rho_u(\lambda).$$

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts $\mu_u$ is called spectral measure. So if I understand very well the definition, then $d E_\lambda$ is only a notation and the integral has a sense when we use the measure $\mu_u$.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Please see the following answer by tomaz: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2802102/square-root-of-positive-operator-on-a-complex-hilbert-space   According to your comments it is wrong. Could you please help me to choose the correct $x_n$? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Borel functional calculus $f\mapsto \int_{\sigma(M)}f(\lambda) \,d E_\lambda$ is a $*$-**homomorphism** from the set of bounded Borel measurable functions to the set of bounded operators on  a Hilbert space. So, you have: $$\int_{\sigma(M)}f(\lambda) \,d E_\lambda\int_{\sigma(M)}g(\lambda) \,d E_\lambda=\int_{\sigma(M)}f(\lambda)g(\lambda) \,d E_\lambda$$ for any bounded Borel measurable functions on $\sigma(M)$.

Comment: Is it true that
$$\left\|\int_{0\leq\lambda\leq 1/n}  \,\mathrm{d}E_\lambda(x)\right\|\leq \int_0^{+\infty}  \,\mathrm{d}E_\lambda(x)=1?$$
Thank you for your help.

Comment: An $*$-homomorphism is automatically contracted，hence $\|\int_{0\leq \lambda\leq \frac{1}{n}} \,d E_\lambda\|\leq \|\chi_{[0, \frac{1}{n}]}\|\leq1=\int_0^\infty \,d E_\lambda$.

Comment: Thank you. But please I don't understand why $x_n$ should be 
 $$x_n=\displaystyle\int_{\{\lambda>1/n\}}\lambda^{-1/2}E_{\lambda}\,\mathrm{d}E_\lambda(x).$$
 and not
  $$x_n=\displaystyle\int_{\{\lambda>1/n\}}\lambda^{-1/2}E_{\lambda}(x)\,\mathrm{d}E_\lambda.$$

Comment: In your question, $E_\lambda$ is a projection-valued measure or spectral measure. The integrand $f$  in the formula $\int f\,d E_\lambda $ should be a complex-valued function.  The correct form of $x_n$ should be $$x_n=(\int_{\{\lambda>\frac{1}{n}\}} \lambda^{-{\frac{1}{2}}}\, dE_\lambda) \circ (E_\lambda (x))=\int_{\{\lambda>\frac{1}{n}\}\cap\{x\} }\lambda^{-{\frac{1}{2}}}\, dE_\lambda .$$

Comment: Thank you for the comment. By the way $\int_{\lambda> 1/n}  \,\mathrm{d}E_\lambda$ is a complex number, however $E_\lambda(x)\in F$ so I don't understand how you use $\circ$? Also $E_\lambda(x)$ depends on  $\lambda$ so it can not go out of the integral

Comment: $\int f \,d E_\lambda$ is an operator on $F$, and I said the $f$ in it is a complex-valued function. I guess that your $E_\lambda(x)$ means $E_\lambda(\{x\})$, to be precise， which is also an operator on $F$.

Comment: Your $x_n$ may be a vector in $F$, but the two formula  you give in the comment  both make no sense as far as I know. Probably you just mean $$x_n=(\int_{\lambda>\frac{1}{n}} \lambda^{-\frac{1}{2}}\,d E_\lambda)(x).$$